# Autofocus on the first empty field in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, autofocus

I am trying to achieve AutoFocus functionality on the first empty form field which can be an input element or any kind i.e.

```
1. textbox
2. radio button
3. Select
4. checkbox
```

I have had a look at the jquery website and tried using the **:input** selector
but I am unable to achieve Autofocus on any input field other than text box.
I have also setup a JS Fiddle,

[Fiddle for code](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep777/t17n279L/)

Can somebody help here?

Comment: Did you even read the question, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 6):

You might need to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to find the inputs with empty values:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:enabled").filter(function () {
        return this.value.trim() == "";
    }).first().focus();
});
```

This will not work if you are using `checkbox`. So for that:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:enabled").filter(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox" || $(this).attr("type") == "radio")
            return $(this).val().trim() == "" || !this.checked;
        else
            return this.value.trim() == "";
    }).first().focus();
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fwrd2rk/**

Comment: Hi Praveen, didn't really work for me, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep777/t17n279L/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the empty/unchecked inputs and set focus to the first element in the matched set, as below.

```
$(function () {
    $("input:enabled").filter(function () {
        return this.type.match(/checkbox|radio/i) && //when it's a checkbox/radio
               !this.checked || //get me a list of unselected ones
               ($.trim(this.value) === ""); // else get me a list of empty inputs
    }).first().focus(); //grab the first from the list and set focus
});
```

Here is [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t17n279L/3/) along the same lines.

[**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/t17n279L/5/) includes textarea and select.